# How to remote control Vagrant installed on Windows, within Linux Subsystem?

Tags: windows, vagrant, windows-subsystem-for-linux

According to the documentation of Vagrant, the topic [WSL and Vagrant](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/other/wsl.html) is advanced.

You need to install Vagrant on Linux, because:

> While the vagrant.exe executable provided by the Vagrant Windows
>   installation is accessible from within the WSL, it will not function
>   as expected.

But I don't want to run Vagrant primarily in Linux. I would like to use Virtual Box, installed on my Windows 10 host. But I don't want to leave Linux bash, just to start Vagrant.

Is there a way to remote control Vagrant from within WSL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is true, that `$ vagrant.exe` would cause unexpected behaviour, because Vagrant (installed on Windows) is unable to handle unix-style paths.

But what actually works:

1. When you are in bash, enter `$ cmd.exe`
2. Perform your Vagrant commands, e.g.: `C:\> vagrant up`
3. And return to bash, using `C:\> exit`

Fortunately [cmd.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/cmd) has got options, which allows us to call Vagrant via cmd.exe:

```
$ cmd.exe /c vagrant up
```

This will launch Windows' command line, perform the command, and return to bash.

Even more cool, when you add this to your **~/.bashrc** file:

```
alias cmd='cmd.exe'
alias vagrant='cmd /c vagrant'
```

You can use the native vagrant commands in WSL bash (performed in Windows):

```
$ vagrant up
```

For me, this works like charm.

*Notice:* I've changed my root mount paths of harddrives from `/mnt/c` to `/c`. When I enter `cmd.exe` I'll end up in the same directory. Windows does convert the paths. But Windows is not able to handle e.g. `~`. Then, Windows will end up in C:\Windows\System32